# Why server controls in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Considering that ASP.net MVC doesn't support PostBack or ViewState, why are server controls available when creating asp.net mvc applications?

Answer (score 2):

They are available only if you are using the WebForms view engine because they come as legacy from classic WebForms. With Razor they are no longer available. Anyway, they should never be used in an ASP.NET MVC application so why care about them? If you are working with an ASP.NET MVC application think of them as something non-existent.